# Prove that if $m\mid (a^2 -1)$ then $m\mid (a^4 -1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, prime-factorization

I have been stuck on this question for quite some time, I have tried several methods but to no avail. I attempted to use prime factorization but I couldn't really see where to go with it.

Comment: Try showing $(a^2 - 1) \mid (a^4 - 1)$. The $m$ just distracts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a^4-1=(a^2)^2-1^2=(a^2-1)(a^2+1) \Rightarrow (a^2-1)|(a^4-1).$

If $m|(a^2-1)\Rightarrow \exists n$ sunch that $a^2-1=mn\Rightarrow a^4-1=mn(a^2+1)\Rightarrow m|(a^4-1)$

Comment: Thank you! all makes perfect sense now!